# The Code doesn't work in JSFiddle

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

I have used a code from this page http://www.pureexample.com/jquery/get-json.html and I pasted into a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3baudg73/1/)

Somehow the code in jsfiddle doesn't work and I also have changed the URL but the problem still remain in jsfiddle. I would like the code to be working in jsfiddle. What problem am I missing?

**HTML:**

```
<a name="#ajax-getjson-example"></a>
<div id="example-section38">
  <div>Car sale report</div>
  <div id="div381"></div>
  <button id="btn382" type="button">Click to load car sale report (json type)</button>
  &nbsp;<a href="http://www.pureexample.com/backend/data/car-sale.json" target="_blank">Original car sale report</a>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn382").click(function() {
    /* set no cache */
    $.ajaxSetup({
      cache: false
    });

    $.getJSON("http://www.pureexample.com/backend/data/car-sale.json", function(data) {
      var html = [];

      /* loop through array */
      $.each(data, function(index, d) {
        html.push("Manufacturer : ", d.Manufacturer, ", ",
          "Sold : ", d.Sold, ", ",
          "Month : ", d.Month, "<br>");
      });

      $("#div381").html(html.join('')).css("background-color", "orange");
    }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { /* assign handler */
      /* alert(jqXHR.responseText) */
      alert("error occurred!");
    });
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Did you see the errors on console?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.pureexample.com/backend/data/car-sale.json?_=1457992354838. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Then it must be the same for js bin? https://jsbin.com/tavarafeli/edit?html,output

Comment: Yes would be the same on any domain other than `pureexample.com`. It's a cross domain request

Comment: Would be the same if I have used the sourcecode in my local client computer? I save the sourcecode in my computer?

Comment: Should work fine on your local PC, assuming the URL for your AJAX call is also local. Research CORS to see why this is happening. Also, you can use an online IDE like c9.io for stuff like this - then you can have the front-end and back-end code.

Comment: No..that ajax request will fail if page is loaded on any other domain due to CORS restrictions

Comment: I have applied the sourcecode in jsbin and you can download the code into you computer but unfortunately, you cannot se the data from json in the local computer. :(

Comment: Please take a look at the picture

Comment: Look up CORS - you cannot pull information from another domain without their allowing it. That site (pureexample.com) apparently doesn't explicitly allow it (by providing an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header), which is why you get the error message regarding cross-origin resource sharing (CORS). If they have an API, and you have a key to use it, that should allow you to authenticate and utilize the information; if they don't, then they probably don't want you wasting their bandwidth. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS